# SSIS: how to create connection manager to SQL Server Package Store

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

In current SSIS solution, I need a connection manager to SQL Package Store (MSDB) where my packages deployed to.

I could connect to MSDB in SSMS by choosing "integration service". But I do not find the same connection type when establishing connection manager in visual studio. The only thing I could use is "Ole DB" connection, which seems could not identify integration service.

P.S. Version of SQL-Sever integration service is 2012. It's using default server name (localhost) and no instance name is set.

Comment: What information do you need from the Package Store? If it's just catalog metadata, use the SSISDB database (or whatever you named it, that's just the default) you created to manage your catalog.

Comment: @Kyle Hale   Yes I am using SSIS DB. But from visual studio, I cannot create a connection manager to my package stored in MSDB folder in SSIS DB.

Comment: You don't create a connection manager to a package? What are you trying to do with the package, exactly? Run it from within another package?

Comment: @Kyle Hale 
Yes, I have a Master package to call and execute all child packages. My child packages have been deployed to SSIS DB so I need to create connection to it in Master pkg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way in SSIS 2012 to execute a package that is part of SSIS 2012 Project deployment model using an Execute Package task unless both the master and child package are in the same project.

So my first question would be: why do you have a master package that is not part of its child package's project (or vice versa)? Clearly they're connected in some non-arbitrary way, so they should probably be part of the same project.

That having been said, the only way to accomplish this is to use an Execute SQL task and invoke SSISDB's internal stored procedures to kick off an execution of your remote package. Please see [this excellent article by Reza Rad](http://rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/70-SSIS-2012-Execute-Package-from-Another-Project.html) on the particulars of those stored procedures.